# How to handle the extra 12451 elements in Sophie-Germain Counter Mode?

Tags: gcm, sgcm

In Sophie-Germain Counter Mode (SGCM), the $GF(2^{128})$ field multiplication of Galois Counter Mode (GCM) is replaced with normal multiplication $\bmod 2^{128}+12451$.  Because the block size is 128 bits, the extra 12451 elements of the group do not fit in the output.

The [SGCM defining document](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/326) says the following about the extra elements:

> Should the value be equal to $2^{128}$ or larger and hence require more than 16 bytes of storage, the result should be truncated $\bmod 2^{128}$.

That is fine, due to the extremely small probability of wrapping, but there are other parts of the document that aren't straightforward.

The value of the multiplier/start point $H = E_k(0)+2$ prevents the pathological cases $H = 0$ and $H = 1$.  ($H = -1$ is also prevented by the construction because $E_k(0)$ is too small.)  But if $E_k(0)+2$ is either $2^{128}$ or $2^{128}+1$, what is supposed to happen to the math?  Is supporting multiplying by a 129-bit number required to handle this case?

I was considering supporting both GCM and SGCM in a client-server application, with SGCM being used when the client is run on a machine without x86 `pclmulqdq` / ARM `pmull`.  I don't think there are security considerations about supporting both based on the client's choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the value be equal to $2^{128}$ or larger and hence require more than 16 bytes of storage, the result should be truncated $\mod 2^{128}$

Note that this talks about the final tag value $Y_n$.  Truncating the final value will reduce security, but only slightly (e.g. possibly doubling the success probability of a forgery attempt, which is tiny even with a doubling).

Truncating intermediate values could potentially greatly increase the potential for forgeries.  At the very least, if you modify the proof giving a bound on the forgery probability, that bound will turn out to be 1 of a long (e.g. 2kbyte or longer) message.  I'm not certain how one could construct such a forgery, but the entire point of (S)GCM is that there is provably no high probability method.

> Is supporting multiplying by a 129-bit number required to handle this case?

Yup.

As an alternative, you might want to look up the [Carter Wegman Counter mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CWC_mode); that is similar to SGCM, but uses the field $GF(2^{127}-1)$ (and divides the message into 15 byte blocks for the authentication pass).